# Find if two multi-dimensional parallelograms intersect

Tags: algorithms

Let $P$ be the $n$-dimensional cube

$$P=\{(x_1,...,x_n):x_i\in [-1,1]\forall i\}$$

Let $Q$ be an $m$-dimensional cube defined by end points $[a_i,b_i]$

$$Q=\{(x_1,...,x_m):x_i\in[a_i,b_i]\}=\prod_{i=1}^m[a_i,b_i]$$

Let $A_{m,n}$ be any matrix, so that $Ax\in\mathbb{R}^m$. We can assume $A$ has full rank.

I need to find if $AP\cap Q$ is non-empty.

Note that $AP$ defines an $n$-dimensional parallelogram in $\mathbb{R}^m$ if $n\le m$. And $Q$ is a cuboid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this problem is to formulate it as a linear program:

> Minimize $y$ subject to the constraints
>
> $-y \le x_j \le y$ for $j = 1,\ldots,n$,
>
> $a_i \le \displaystyle\sum_{j = 1}^{n}A_{i,j}x_j \le b_i$, for $i = 1,\ldots,m$.

Or in the standard LP form:

> Minimize $\begin{bmatrix}0_{1 \times n} & 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}$ subject to $\begin{bmatrix}-I_{n \times n}&-1_{n \times 1}\\I_{n \times n}&-1_{n \times 1}\\-A&0_{m \times 1}\\A&0_{m \times 1}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix} \le \begin{bmatrix}0_{n \times 1}\\0_{n \times 1}\\-a\\b\end{bmatrix}$.

It is easy to check that the optimal solution $(x^*,y^*)$ to this LP satisfies $y^* \le 1$ if and only if $AP \cap Q$ is non-empty.

Comment: Yes that's exactly how I did it, used a LP solver. Notice this problem is simpler than a full LP, since all I am interested in is if the feasible region is non-empty. Also there are some nice symmetries. I was wondering if there is any direct way to solve this problem.